# can we open an UDP conection in javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, udp

I think all is in the title, I want to use socket in js with UDP. I tried with WebSocket but : Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'udp' is not allowed. Is it possible with socket.io ? if yes how to use socket.io without node.js ? Maybe ther is a socket.io.min.js.
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: No, you'd have to open to a websocket or http connection to a server and bridge to UDP from there.

Comment: You can with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html). However, I'm guessing you mean _from a browser_.

Comment: it's probably easier to just make the other end use websockets

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection. There are UDP sockets, and they can be 'connected', which is really just a filtering operation. No connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Websocket connections are an ['upgrade' based on HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.2), an HTTP is [based on TCP/IP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2). So, inherently, you cannot open a UDP connection, since for even getting a websocket connection started, you will already have a TCP/IP connection going.

However, if you really do need UDP, you could implement something on your server side that actually does the UDP connection and act as a proxy, where your server opens the UDP connection with more low level libraries. You are of course less limited on the server than you are in a browser.